# Why can't I install Ubuntu on my Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Pro?

Tags: system-installation

After several attempts, I cannot even install the latest Ubuntu onto my Fujitsu Siemens Amilo Pro. It is running Windows Vista and I even attempted to install it using Windows, which still failed. I also attempted to install for a USB stick, which would get the Ubuntu 13.10 screen with the colour changing blocks, this would be there for a while and then the screen would go black with no install or try screen appearing, just black. Is there any way to solve this without messing with code as I have no experience with coding!

Comment: For the USB disk installation, you can see - [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075).

can't say why windows installation (via wubi.exe) is failed, without any error code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run your Live Ubuntu DVD / USB, do not choose to install Ubuntu from the boot menu, instead choose the first option **Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer** to be able to boot into a live session. Once you are in the Live session, make sure you have an Internet connection (configure your network if necessary from the system tray using the network manager).

Next, you can choose to install Ubuntu using Live Installer icon that is present on your desktop. When presented with the 3 choices for installing Ubuntu in dual-boot with Windows Vista, choose the 3rd one saying **Something else**. You will be getting to the partition table for your hard-disk, and you can choose the partition where you want to install Ubuntu. Make sure you divide that partition into 2 separate partitions, a large partition formatted as linux ext4 for **root** with foreslash **/** as startup point, and a smaller partition (up to 2GB in size) formatted as linux swap.

Now you can select the root partition that you have previously created and press NEXT to continue installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, this was interesting! I actually managed to figure it out myself! I had to burn Ubuntu to a DVD, insert the DVD whilst running Windows, run the Wubi installation, shut down. Reinsert DVD, boot up. Press F12, Hard drive. ESC, Safe Graphical Installer and then follow the standard instructions.